# Geometry reference-request

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I would like some reference regarding geometry. I'm a student of civil engineering, and I wanted some insight in general geometry, e.g, know what originated it, what is valid today, etc. In specific, a book with rigorous explanations of analytic geometry would help a lot. Resuming: I want a book that "situates" me in time, and that explains generals terms of geometry and their respective development. Of course, I know *some* things, but a general overview would be better, can't afford mediocrity.

I want to ask also what is the most valid geometry used today. I know we have non-Euclidean geometries, but what is the most suitable for working in engineering? Euclidean it's fine? It's recomendable to read it directly from the "Elements"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to limit the selection to one book. One that I have always enjoyed is " Geometry and the Imagination " by David Hilbert and S. Cohn-Vossen . But I'll write down a few authors that come to mind. " Introduction to Geometry" by H.S.M. Coxeter, a great Geometer and expositer . Perhaps also  "Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries: Development and History" by  Marvin J. Greenberg .

That said, there are a number of excellent Geometry books available at archive.org, 
hundreds in fact and many of them are excellent. There is also something of a rating system to allow you to judge by the number of downloads which books are great. I'd actually check there first! I found my college Differential Geometry book, " Elementary Differential Geometry" by Barrett O'Neill there. Quite a find.

I haven't mentioned Analytic Geometry -  something you might actually use on a regular basis, but I would consider searching archive.org just for a start.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. I founded Greenberg's very interesting, maybe I start with this one.